# R- delete the tail word

Tags: r

Can someone teach me how to delete tail word ,thanks.

from

```
 1 North Africa                                 
 2 Algeria                                      
 3 Canary Islands (Spain)[153]                  
 4 Ceuta (Spain)[154]
```

to

```
 1 North Africa                                 
 2 Algeria                                      
 3 Canary Islands                
 4 Ceuta
```

I'm sad with my poor English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you want to trim a trailing name in parentheses, along with anything which follows to the end of the string.  We can use `sub` for this purpose:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1:4),
    places=c("North Africa", "Algeria", "Canary Islands (Spain)[153]", "Ceuta (Spain)[154]"),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df$places <- sub("\\s*\\(.*\\).*$", "", df$places)
df

  id         places
1  1   North Africa
2  2        Algeria
3  3 Canary Islands
4  4          Ceuta
```

Comment: Nothing really changes, just call `sub` on the data frame column.